# Login in particular react component using Jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have to write the test case for this particular component as given below:-

```
import React from 'react';

import auth from 'containers/Login/authService';
class Footer extends React.Component {


    render() {

      if(!auth.loggedIn()){
        return (
          <div className="hidden">Not Logged In</div>
        );
      }else
        return (
            <footer>
                <span>XYZ</span>
            </footer>
        );
    }

}

export default Footer;
```

I have done the testing for *Not Logged In* part, but I am unable to test for the *XYZ* part. My test case file is as below:-

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Footer from '../Footer';
import { login } from '../../../containers/Login/authService';

describe('Footer mount testing', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Footer />);

  it('For not logged in user', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.hidden').length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });


  it('For logged in user', () => {
    jest.mock('../../../containers/Login/authService', () => ({
      login: true,
    }));
    login.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('true'));
    expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('XYZ');
  });
});
```

While running this I always get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockImplementation' of undefined`

I am not able to login in this particular module in order to check.

containers/Login/authService file as below:-

```
import request from 'utils/request';
import {config} from 'utils/config';
let localStorage;

// If we're testing, use a local storage polyfill
if (global.process && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  localStorage = require('localStorage');
} else {
  // If not, use the browser one
  localStorage = global.window.localStorage;
}

let auth = {
  /**
   * Logs a user in, returning a promise with `true` when done
   * @param  {string} username The username of the user
   * @param  {string} password The password of the user
   */
  login (username, password) {
    if (auth.loggedIn()) return Promise.resolve(true);

var data ={username:username, password:password}
    console.log("#" + data + "#");

    let requestData = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": "Basic d2ViX2FwcDo="
      },
      body : JSON.stringify(data)
    };

    return request.post(config.serverHost+'/api/core/login', requestData)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('response received',response);
        // Save token to local storage
       // if(response.status == 200)
        localStorage.token = JSON.stringify(response);
        return Promise.resolve(response)
      })
  },

  logout () {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      resolve(true)
    });

  },
  /**
   * Checks if a user is logged in
   */
  loggedIn () {
    return !!localStorage.token
  },

export default auth
```

Comment: What does your auth service file look like? Are you exporting login as a named export?

Comment: @shadymoses Let me upload that as well, it will give you a clear picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mockImplementation` cannot be used on `login` because it's not a function. It doesn't make sense to mock it in `Footer` test because the nearest unit to mock is `loggedIn`.

A proper unit test is:

```
jest.spyOn(auth, 'loggedIn').mockReturnValue(true);
const wrapper = mount(<Footer />);
expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('XYZ');
```

The problem with this test suite is that tests are cross-contaminated. `mount` should be done in `beforeEach`, not in `describe` scope.

Comment: I am getting this particular error *TypeError: jest.spyOn is not a function*
I have already upgraded my jest but still, it's not working @estus

Comment: Are you saying that there was no problems with `jest.mock` but there's a problem with `jest.spyOn`? I have no explanation for that since both methods are core Jest API, https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object

Comment: I manage to tackle the previous problem but this is the current error it's throwing *TypeError: jest.spyOn(...).returnValue is not a function*. I tried to replace the returnValue(false) with mockReturnValueOnce(false) and mockReturnValue(false). But I am still not able to log in as user and test my component @estus

Comment: Sorry, that's `mockReturnValue` indeed. Try to mock it before rendering the component, updated the code. There may be problems with `wrapper.update()`, another problem is that the component will be initially rendered with unmocked `auth` and cause side effects that can break the test.

Comment: const spy = jest.spyOn(auth, 'loggedIn').mockReturnValue(false);<br>
const wrap = mount(<Footer data={spy} />);<br>
expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('XYZ');<br>







I tried in the above manner but still I am not able to log in as a user. @estus

Comment: It should be `true` instead of `false` to render 'else` condition, shouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It was true and it's still isn't working now. The same error cannot log in as a user. @estus

Comment: What is the exact error? I see no 'cannot log in as user' message in the code you posted. Any way, this is how it should be tested, I would expect current code to work.

Comment: It's working now. It was a mistake from my end while testing.
Thank You! @estus